# SUMIFS "not blank" "<>" does not works

Tags: excel

I tried to make a `SumIfs` formula with a criteria of *not blank* in an Excel Spreadsheet.

If I change the formula for *criteria 2* to one range, for example as column `P:P`, it's working.

Works :
`=sumifs('Sheet1'!H:H,'Sheet1'!C:C,C10,'Sheet1'!P:P,"<>")`

But if I change the formula for *criteria 2* as more than one column, for example set as range `P:V` it's not working?

Does not work :
`=sumifs('Sheet1'!H:H,'Sheet1'!C:C,C10,'Sheet1'!P:V,"<>")`

The formula returns the `#VALUE!` error.
Array arguments to `SUMIFS` are of different size.

Criteria 2 are random text.

Comment: dimensions on sheet 1 C:C and Sheet1 P:V need to match. Did you mean Sheet1 P:P (or V:V). Otherwise, you need to list as separate criteria. See https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumifs-function

Comment: @JeremyKahan Why don't you post that as an answer? You'll get my upvote.

Comment: @teylyn, I was not sure enough at the time (I'm on a mac which does not have Excel), so I was taking a guess. Since then, it has been posted as an answer by someone who knew what he was talking about, so mine would add nothing.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 6):

Use "><" instead of "<>"

Answer (score 0):

excel sumifs doesn't handle 2 columns in parallel
You should seperate columns P and V and should work, assuming you won't the amount summed only if the cells in both columns are blanks

```
=sumifs('Sheet1'!H:H,'Sheet1'!C:C,C10,'Sheet1'!P:P,"<>"'Sheet1'!V:V, "<>")
```